Convert XY to W3W
I have been told by our water company that our meter is at
X Coordinate: 526585.0
Y Coordinate: 181591.0
I have tried to identify the location using various maps without success. How can I convert to What3Words?

It would be helpful to know, where you live. This would narrow down the CRS choices. Furthermore "using various maps" is very vague. What did you do, exactly? Using which map?

Our school is in London. I'm not a GIS expert so just used basic maps

So... you looked on a paper map?

No. Google and Bing. We don't have paper maps in school

Anyway. Those coordinates should be British National Grid, EPSG-code 27700 and land you somewhere north of Paddington - https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=27700&t_srs=4326&x=526585.7500000&y=181591.7500000

Based on your British National Grid Coordinates

https://webapps.bgs.ac.uk/data/webservices/convertForm.cfm#bngToLatLng
Easting: 526585
Longitude: -0.176959
Northing: 181591
Latitude: 51.519063
converted here 
https://www.geocachingtoolbox.com/index.php?lang=en&page=w3w
w3w
is:
noisy.sculpture.pushy

If the coordinate you have are in epsg 27700 (OSGB36 / British National Grid) that locate your meter at

lon : -0°10'36.965"
Lat: 51°31'8.634"

(or for google map : 51°31'08.6"N 0°10'37.0"E)
in epsg 4326 (WGS84).
This seem to be in the London greater area in Rainham, close to the crossing of Manor Way and Consul Avenue (see map below for a general view)


Wouldn't that be 0°10' West?
